# Winston daily rotate remove .GZIP files

Tags: node.js, logging, zip, gzip, winston

currently im zipping the files daily with `winston daily rotate`. The thing I want to do now is remove the `zip files` after a week. is there a possibility to accomplish this by using `winston daily rotate` or do i have to write it myself ?

Code im using:

```
const transport = new (winston.transports.DailyRotateFile)({
    "name": "basic-log",
    "filename": `${logDir}/%DATE%-log`,
    "datePattern": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "zippedArchive": true,
    "colorize": false,
    "maxFiles": '2d'
});

transport.on('rotate', function(oldFilename, newFilename) {
    // do something fun
    console.log(new Date(), oldFilename, newFilename)

});

const logger = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        transport
    ]
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

currently (winston-daily-rotate-file v.3.3.3) doesn't delete zipped files. 
Open bug: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-daily-rotate-file/issues/125

Answer (score 0):

In `winston-daily-rotate-file` you can set `maxFiles: '7d'` which will delete the files that are older than a week.

From `winston-daily-rotate-file`:

> maxFiles: Maximum number of logs to keep. If not set, no logs will be removed. This can be a number of files or number of days. If using days, add 'd' as the suffix. (default: null)

read more about it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-daily-rotate-file#usage